# Cannot switch on debugging mode in Flask and Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I think I'm doing what is recommened, by switching on debug mode. I'm doing the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.debug = True
```

Which should switch on debug mode. However, when trying to examine a POST, I get the following error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in
>   the application.

The code I am using to examine the POST from JS is:

```
@app.route('/signedin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signedin():
    profile = {}
    profile['name'] = ''
    profile['email'] = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':

        profile['name'] = request.form.get('name')
        profile['email'] = request.form.get('email')

    return render_template('summary.html', profile=profile)
```

I would try and problem solve this, but I seem to not be able to switch on debug.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying, such as having signedin() simply print something? This would be without messing with debug=True for now. If the problem doesn't manifest, then continue building back up until it fails. The other direction is to start with a bare-bones Flask app that has debugging working (start with the tutorial) and build up from there. Not trying to insult, just establishing a debugging baseline.

Answer (score 1):

Is the server running with app.run()? Also if the request is coming from a different computer you must set the host to be 0.0.0.0 (see doc)

> If you have debug disabled or trust the users on your network, you can make the server publicly available simply by changing the call of the run() method to look like this:
>
> > app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
> >     #This tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.

Running this returns no server error so it is fine.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/signedin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signedin():
     profile = {}
     profile['name'] = ''
     profile['email'] = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':

        profile['name'] = request.form.get('name')
        profile['email'] = request.form.get('email')

    return render_template('summary.html', profile=profile)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Also, remember to pass in your kwargs to the templates like:
    {{ profile }}